# Is there an easy way to link AWS Cloudfront authorization to Google Workspaces?

Tags: amazon-web-services, g-suite, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-lambda

Is there an easy way to link AWS Cloudfront authorisation to Google Workspaces?

I'm trying to achieve single sign on to a Cloudfront hosted static website such that anyone with a corporate email address (from google workspaces) can sign in.

What I understand so far is that something like this should be achievable via Lambda@Edge dialling out to [Google OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2).

But at this point the trail goes cold. I'm struggling to find that missing link of a working Lambda@Edge to connect with google authentication.

I've seen a number of anecdotal reports that this is possible, but none with working examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I discovered someone had a sample project which can be deployed through CloudFront.  This contains the necessary Javascript for a working lambda@edge function:

https://github.com/aws-samples/lambdaedge-openidconnect-samples

We found the cloud-front configuration wouldn't quite fit our requirements but this was a great start.

It's particularly important to follow the documented [Steps For Setup](https://github.com/aws-samples/lambdaedge-openidconnect-samples?tab=readme-ov-file#steps-for-setup)